# Android network usage on main thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, http

So, i have been creating and application for a client and got to the network part. I am currently removing the targetSDK tag from the manifest so i dont get a MainThreadException. I have seen people and documentation about saying i should not do network operations on not the mainthread as it is slower...

The Question: where and how do i do network operations without doing it on the main thread?
Here's the code:

```
  public static class MagFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_MAGAZINE_NUMBER = "magazine_number";

    public MagFragment() {
        // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_MAGAZINE_NUMBER);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        if(i != 0){
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_magazine, container, false);
            TextView magText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textViewMag);

            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://csddata.site11.com");
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream inputstream = httpEntity.getContent();
                try{

                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputstream,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                    magText.setText(reader.readLine());

                }catch (Exception e){
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }

        String magazine = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.magazine_array)[i];
        Log.d("MagFragment", "MagNumber" + i);

        getActivity().setTitle(magazine);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you read this: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

Comment: And if you are doing the next big thing consider this: http://developers.google.com/live/shows/474338138/ ;-)

Comment: i've done stuff where i just create a thread class, create an object, pass it the variables it needs and call its start. more on threads http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html

Comment: I have looked at the network basic ops, one other problem... Because its in the Fragmemt then i have to put getActivity() to the line       'ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);' which makes the 'new DownloadWebpageTask().execute(stringUrl);' have an error of "No enclosing instance of type MainActivity is accessible."

Comment: @DrDebug If you are still having problems with the sample app/integrating it into your own, rewrite the question to reflect the changes mades (or write a new one) and specify exactly what is failing.

Answer (score 1):

No, no, no, do not implement this yourself unless you're doing it to learn about threading and async task. Instead of reinventing the wheel and spending ages on debugging and trying to figure out how to handle retries, thread pools, cookies and what not I suggest that you use an existing library that's built on top of the Android classes and abstracts away all the tedious and error prone code.

You should use something like [Android Async Http Client](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/), it is "An asynchronous callback-based Http client for Android built on top of Apache’s HttpClient libraries. All requests are made outside of your app’s main UI thread, but any callback logic will be executed on the same thread as the callback was created using Android’s Handler message passing."

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of the class [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). It does not run on the main thread , but you can call it from the main thread. You can let your activity waiting until your asynctask is ready. In the meantime you can show a progressbar on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way and i've done stuff like this,  you can implement a thread class, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html

you have the object and pass it the variables you want it to have, then start the thread. Seems all you want to do is set the text of something so you could pass it that object that it needs to set the text of and there doesn't seem to be a lot more to it. Just move your http request stuff to the thread class's run.  There is no guarantee of timing once you start a thread, it can finish a little later or something but if you just want to update a textview that probably enough.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do this? Use an AsyncTask to send Requests. Do you want to notify your Class after it's finished? Use a Callback Listener. It's easy.

here is my example (not tested)

```
public void doNetworkStuff() {
    new doAsyncNetworkStuff().execute(this);
}

@Override
 public void onTaskCompleted(String str) {
}


private class doSingleRequest extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Void> {

private HttpInterface httpInterface;

public doSingleRequest(HttpInterface httpInterface) {
    this.httpInterface = httpInterface;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
 //do your inits and so on
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Object... params) {
   //do your background network stuff
        httpInterface.onTaskCompleted(str);

    return null;
}
}
```

Here is the HttpInterface
      public interface HttpInterface {
    void onTaskCompleted(String str);
    }

How does it work? You are calling an Asynctask which do your network stuff with a Callback Listener. After this is done the Callbacklistener with onTaskCompleted get called. This means your Mainclass will get notified with the buffer or whatever. You can process with all your stuff after that without blocking. Enjoy.